Drop down List to hide rows from one sheet to others
I want to have a drop down list with the name for example calculations, other and with choosing one I can have certain rows hidden on another sheet.
Is there an easy way to do that?
I tried some codes but I do not understand the syntax since I am pulling from another sheet the cell value and changing on to three more sheets
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheets("Project&Site_Details").Rows("4:8").EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(Me.Range("c4").Value2 = "Server Migration", True, False)
End Sub

This one keeps asking me for macro name.
So the basic idea is a dropdown on sheet Project&Site_Details on cell C4 with three names Server Migration, Data Type, Other. and have them hide or show rows on three different sheets according to the sheet. like Pre_Checklist, Post_Checklist
I got it to work using this code
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("C4")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If KeyCells = "Server Migration" Then
            Sheets(3).Rows("4:4").Hidden = True
            Sheets(3).Rows("5:5").Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets(3).Rows("4:4").Hidden = False
            Sheets(3).Rows("5:5").Hidden = False
        End If
        If KeyCells = "Add-On" Then
            Sheets(3).Rows("10:11").Hidden = True
        Else
            Sheets(3).Rows("10:11").Hidden = False
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub

Is there any simpler way?

You mention three more sheets, but your code only refers to two sheets. Try replacing Me  by the actual worksheet containing the cell referred to; it works for me.

Why don't you explain your requirement in detail? "I am pulling from another sheet the cell value and changing on to three more sheets" could mean a lot of different things. List all sheet names and cell addresses and whether they contain values or formulas...

Worksheet_Change is an Event.    We can not run it.  It will trigger when you change a cell value on the worksheet that has the event in its module.  Watch:Excel VBA: The Magic of the Worksheet Change Event.

Please edit your question instead of adding information in comments

Consider using Select Case when evaluating a single value. Watch: Excel VBA Introduction Part 14 - Select Case Statements
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "C4" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Server Migration"
                Sheets(3).Rows("4:4").Hidden = True
                Sheets(3).Rows("5:5").Hidden = True
            Case "Add-On"
                Sheets(3).Rows("10:11").Hidden = True
            Case Else
                Sheets(3).Rows("4:4").Hidden = False
                Sheets(3).Rows("5:5").Hidden = False
                Sheets(3).Rows("10:11").Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

